# why does this PHP code not work with 'Post' method?

Tags: php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['n']) && isset($_POST['pass']) ) {
    echo 'success';
}
?>

<form action="first.php" method="POST">
    name:<br> <input type="text" name="n"><br>
    Password:<br> <input type="text" name="pass">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

ps: this works if i use GET instead of POST, i am new to web development so any help is appreciated.

Comment: this should obviously works. don't know you you have a `switch_post_to_get` module on your web server, or something else. but the problem isn't in your code

Comment: The only way this should break is if the variables_order php.ini setting doesn't contain "P". But that sounds incredibly unlikely.

Comment: i checked my php.ini file, the setting is a followsvariables_order = "GPCS"

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine, perhaps $_REQUEST has the values? Try....

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['n']) && isset($_REQUEST['pass']) ) {
```

Either way, something sounds funky with your web server.

FYI $_REQUEST is an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Comment: i tried it with $_REQUEST but still no luck, i guess something's wrong with my web server